# c++ long long int is not enough?? errors

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

I am working in c++. I have a string that contains the following number

```
std::string s= "8133522648";
```

I want to convert this number in

```
long long int nr;
```

I did: `nr=atoll(s.c_str()).` The `result is: -456410944`. How to solve this error? Thanks

Edit:

In fact I have:

```
const char* str="8133523648";
I have to convert it into long long int nr=8133523648
```

Thanks for help! Appreciate!

Comment: did you mean `std::string s = "8133522648";` ? And `atoll(s.c_str())` ?

Comment: Also, shouldn't nr=atoll(s) rather be nr=atoll(s.c_str())?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Could you kindly post a compileable example?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use int64_t instead of long long. which is defined in stdint.h

If you rely on boost you can use

```
std::string s= "8133522648";
int64_t nr = boost::lexical_cast<int64_t, std::string>(s);
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference - all standards that define `int64_t` also define `long long` as a >= 64 bit type.

Comment: stdint.h will probably work on most compilers but is no C++ standard.

Comment: Good to know. My c++ book is just saying that i should better use int64_t, uint32_t...

Comment: @Mythli: Then see the [Definitive c++ book guide and list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in better way as follows:

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream sstr;
sstr << "8133522648";

long long nr;
sstr >> nr;
```

Don't use `atoll()` as it is not defined by C++ standard. Some compiler may implement it while others don't. Also,

```
std::string s = 8133522648;
```

doesn't mean

```
std::string s = "8133522648";
```

which was probably what you wanted.

Comment: atoll is in C standard, so when he includes <cstdlib> it will be working.. Every compiler will be working.. Question is that he has library..

Comment: @nirmus: the question is tagged C++, and neither `atoll` nor `long long` are defined in C++03. However, you can probably assume that most compilers that support `long long` also support `atoll`.

Comment: @mike: i didn't know `long long` isn't defined by C++03. :(

Comment: i am working in ubuntu and i compile with g++. I ve edited my question. need help

Comment: @Donotalo: It's in C++11, which modern compilers are currently implementing. So there's no real surpise if it works.

Comment: @msalter: yep. actually i've been using `long long` type for so long that i've forgotten it hasn't been standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

       std::string s= "8133522648";
       long long int nr = atoll(s.c_str());
       cout << nr;
    }
```